# PHP exec command not returning anything

Tags: php, linux, bash, magento, magento-1.9

I'm trying to run the below script from a php file but im not getting anything retuned on the command line. The code i have before and after this snippet runs fine, but with this section, I get nothing. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

```
$url = "https://myAddressHere.co.uk"
$output = null;
$retval = null;
exec("wget --execute robots=off --recursive --no-parent --no-clobber --delete-after --no-check-certificate --no-cache --no-cookies --user-agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36' --reject jpg,jpeg,png,gif,bmp,svg,pdf,doc ".$url, $output, $retval);
echo "Returned with the status ". $retval . "and output:\n";
var_dump($output);
```

When I run this from the command line

```
wget --execute robots=off --recursive --no-parent --no-clobber --delete-after --no-check-certificate --no-cache --no-cookies --user-agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36' --reject jpg,jpeg,png,gif,bmp,svg,pdf,doc https://myAddressHere.co.uk
```

It works fine but I need it to run from the php script.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wget is a tool for making web requests. PHP has built in functionality for doing that.

Comment: I suspect you need to redirect STDERR in order to get the info from ‘wget’. Ie, add “ 2>&1 “ at the end of your ‘wget’ command string.

Comment: Probably `/some/path/to/wget`